# Custom Inputs in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

How to let user change the value of the avg and pbv in the script settings interface?

```
indicator("myindicator")
avg = ta.sma(volume, 3)
pbv = (volume > avg*1.3)
plotshape(pbv, "R", shape.triangleup, location.abovebar, color.purple)
```

Answer (score 0):

`avg` and `pbv` are results of some calculations. The user cannot change their values directly.

What they can do is, change the `sma` length and that `1.3` multiplier. So they can change those variables indirectly.

```
indicator("myindicator")
length = input.int(3, "Length")
mult = input.float(1.3, "Multiplier", step=0.1)

avg = ta.sma(volume, length)
pbv = (volume > avg * mult)
plotshape(pbv, "R", shape.triangleup, location.abovebar, color.purple)
```